# Regex for unique user count

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex to check the number of unique users.
In this case, 3 different users in 1 string means it's valid.
Let's say we have the following string

> lab\simon;lab\lieven;lab\tim;\lab\davy;lab\lieven

It contains the domain for each user (lab) and their first name.
Each user is seperated by ;

The goal is to have 3 unique users in a string.
In this case, the string is valid because we have the following unique users

> simon, lieven, tim, davy = valid

If we take this string

> lab\simon;lab\lieven;lab\simon

It's invalid because we only have 2 unique users

> simon, lieven = invalid

So far, I've only come up with the following regex but I don't know how to continue

```
/(lab)\\(?:[a-zA-Z]*)/g
```

Could you help me with this regex?

Please let me know if you need more information if it's not clear.

Comment: Which engine are you using?

Comment: This sounds like a job for string splitting and ordering, not regular expressions.

Comment: do you wish the usernames to be mutually unique or just any three in a string, e.g., simon, liven, simon = [in]valid?

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. Today I'm working on another project so I don't have time to test these solutions right now. I will update this thread once I get time to test.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after cannot be achieved through regular expressions on their own. Regular expressions are to be used for parsing information and not processing.

There is no particular pattern you are after, which is what regular expression excel at. You will need to split by `;` and use a data structure such as a set to store you string values.

Comment: in this case, I guess you can if you force the regex to match at least 3 groups.

Comment: @PedroLobito: Yes but I'd hardly call the solution scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

1) Using regular expression:

```
import re

s = r'lab\simon;lab\lieven;lab\tim;\lab\davy;lab\lieven'
pattern = re.compile(r'lab\\([A-z]{1,})')
user = re.findall(pattern, s)

if len(user) == len(set(user)) and len(user) >= 3:
    print('Valid')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

2) Without using regular expression:

```
s = r'lab\simon;lab\lieven;lab\tim;\lab\davy;lab\lieven'
users = [i.split('\\')[-1] for i in s.split(';')]

if len(users) == len(set(users)) and len(users) >= 3:
    print('Valid')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a successful match, we need **at least** 3 sets of `lab\user`, i.e:

```
(?:\\?lab\\[\w]+(?:;|$)){3}
```

You didn't specify your engine but with `python`you can use:

```
import re

if re.search(r"(?:\\?lab\\[\w]+(?:;|$)){3}", string):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY4iD6/5)

---

**Regex Explanation**

```
(?:\\?lab\\[\w]+(?:;|$)){3}

Match the regular expression «(?:\\?lab\\[\w]+(?:;|$)){3}»
   Exactly 3 times «{3}»
   Match the backslash character «\\?»
      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match the character string “lab” literally «lab»
   Match the backslash character «\\»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” «[\w]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the regular expression below «(?:;|$)»
      Match this alternative «;»
         Match the character “;” literally «;»
      Or match this alternative «$»
         Assert position at the end of a line «$»
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a beginner-friendly way to solve your problem:

1. You should .split() the string per each "lab" section and declare the result as the array variable, like splitted_string.
2. Declare a second empty array to save each unique name, like unique_names.
3. Use a for loop to iterate through the splitted_string array. Check for unique names: if it isn't in your array of unique_names, add the name to unique_names.
4. Find the length of your array of unique_names to see if it is equal to 3. If yes, print that it is. If not, then print a fail message.

You seem like a practical person that is relatively new to string manipulation. Maybe you would enjoy some practical background reading on string manipulation at beginner sites like Automate The Boring Stuff With Python:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter6/
Or Codecademy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple regex.
Uses a conditional for each user name *slot* so that the required
three names are obtained.

Note that since the three *slots* are in a loop, the conditional guarantees the
capture group is not overwritten (which would invalidate the below mentioned
assertion test `(?! \1 | \2 | \3 )`.

There is a complication. Each user name uses the same regex `[a-zA-Z]+` 
so to accommodate that, a function is defined to check that the *slot*
has not been matched before.

This is using the boost engine, that cosmetically requires the group be
defined before it is back referenced.
The workaround is to define a function at the bottom after the group is defined.

In PERL (and some other engines) it is not required to define a group ahead
of time before its back referenced, so you could do away with the function
and put

```
(?! \1 | \2 | \3 )       # Cannot have seen this user
[a-zA-Z]+
```

in the capture groups on top.

At a minimum, this requires conditionals.

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 # (?:(?:.*?\blab\\(?:((?(1)(?!))(?&GetUser))|((?(2)(?!))(?&GetUser))|((?(3)(?!))(?&GetUser))))){3}(?(DEFINE)(?<GetUser>(?!\1|\2|\3)[a-zA-Z]+))

 # Look for 3 unique users
 (?:
      (?:
           .*? 
           \b lab \\    
           (?:
                (                   # (1), User 1
                     (?(1) (?!) )
                     (?&GetUser) 
                )
             |  (                   # (2), User 2
                     (?(2) (?!) )
                     (?&GetUser) 
                )
             |  (                   # (3), User 3
                     (?(3) (?!) )
                     (?&GetUser) 
                )
           )
      )
 ){3}

 (?(DEFINE)
      (?<GetUser>                   # (4)
           (?! \1 | \2 | \3 )       # Cannot have seen this user
           [a-zA-Z]+ 
      )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pure regex answer for the sport. As other said, you should probably not be doing this

```
^([^;]+)(;\1)*;((?!\1)[^;]+)(;(\1|\3))*;((?!\1|\3)[^;]+)
```

Explanation :

```
^                 from the start of the string
([^;]+)           we catch everything that isn't a ';'.
                   that's our first user, and our first capturing group
(;\1)*            it could be repeated
;((?!\1)[^;]+)    but at some point, we want to capture everything that isn't either
                   our first user nor a ';'. That's our second user,
                   and our third capturing group
(;(\1|\3))*       both the first and second user can be repeated now
;((?!\1|\3)[^;]+) but at some point, we want to capture yada yada,
                   our third user and fifth capturing group
```