# RegEx match the first occurance of a word, from a list of desired words

Tags: regex, regex-group

I seem to have hit upon a corner case - or it's so easy, no one has ever asked!

I have a list of desired words I'd like to match in a block of text. However, I only want to match the first occurrence of *each* of these, (edit: *if* they exist in the target block).

If my block of text reads:

```
glass shoes door doors window door glasses. glass's glass window windows glasses
```

I'd like to match:

```
glass door window
```

I'm learning how to narrow it down as I try to understand the groupings... This:

/(?:[\s]|^)door|glass|window(?=[\s]|$)/g;

gives me "ghost" occurrences:

```
glass, door, door,window, door,glass,glass,glass,window,glass
```

Wrapping my desired words in brackets as a set (group?) like this:

```
/(?:[\s]|^)(door|glass|window)(?=[\s]|$)/g;
```

gives me only every actual occurrence:

```
glass, door, window, door, glass, window
```

which is so far the best (narrowest) I can get.

I would have expected that:

```
/(door|glass|window)/
```

without the /g global flag would give me the first occurrence of "my" OR "desired" OR "words", but it stops at the first find, "glass".

So to restate the question, **(edited)** I'm trying to find the first instance of *each* of these words (first door, and first window, and first glass), *if* they show up at all, wrapped by (?:[\s]|^) and (?=[\s]|$), in a block of text.

Many thanks!

Comment: Use 3 different regexes for each search. It will be the most "readable" approach. [This](https://regex101.com/r/UfIbeo/1) is unweildly and does not make much sense.

Comment: Will give it a try. A constraint is that I can only call ".match" once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Out of order matching**
( For more *advanced* out of order matching see:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734288/regex-to-grab-text-if-code-exists/35734881) and 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128891/regex-for-unique-user-count/33131753#33131753)
)

This can easily be done in a single match.
You could do this if you have a small, fixed amount of words to match.

This requires all the words be there.
(With a slight modification, each word can be optional)

`^(?=.*?(door))(?=.*?(glass))(?=.*?(window))`

Expanded

```
 ^
 (?=
      .*? 
      ( door )                      # (1)
 )
 (?=
      .*? 
      ( glass )                     # (2)
 )
 (?=
      .*? 
      ( window )                    # (3)
 )
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 12 , len 4 ) 
door  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 0 , len 5 ) 
glass  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 23 , len 6 ) 
window
```

***Additional - Make items optional***

The tweak to make items optional:

`^(?=.*?(?:door|window|glass))(?=.*?(door))?(?=.*?(glass))?(?=.*?(window))?`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?=                   # Prevent matching nothing.
      .*? 
      (?: door | window | glass )  # At least one should exist
 )
 (?=
      .*? 
      ( door )              # (1), Optiional first door
 )?
 (?=
      .*? 
      ( glass )             # (2), Optiional first glass
 )?
 (?=
      .*? 
      ( window )            # (3), Optiional first window
 )?
```

Comment: This is a great start, and it helps me understand matching a groups quite a bit better. Thank you. What would the modification be to make the words optional?

Comment: @DavidSzego - Added a regex to make words optional. Don't forget to vote if you find answers helpful.